# Can I use forward geocoding to substitute for an address autocomplete feature?

Tags: ios, autocomplete, mapkit, geocoding

I'm trying to use `geocodeAddressString:inRegion:completionHandler:` to translate partially completed addresses to possible complete address equivalents.

It has odd behavior while doing this, and it doesn't give me the results I want until I'm one letter from the complete address anyway.

For example (limiting results to within 50 miles of san francisco):

- "900 Dolo" reveals "900 Polo" & "900 Yolo" - This doesn't even make sense.
- "900 Dolore" reveals all the results I want such as as the "900 Dolores" addresses in the bay area, but I'm practically done typing the address at that point.

Is this something that's impossible to do with this method call? Or is there a different way to be using it? Does anyone have any other suggestions?

I'm using the Apple maps MKMapKit to place the pin once a user clicks the autocompleted address, which means I can't use the Google Maps/Places API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use forward geocoding for autocomplete.

First of all it's a server request and it will take some time to get the response, second,from apple doc

> After initiating a forward-geocoding request, do not attempt to
>   initiate another forward- or reverse-geocoding request

So you can't perform multiple request for forward geocoding as you would for an autocomplete.

Comment: The server request is of a negligible amount of time actually. All of the autocomplete implementations use server requests to gather possible addresses, just look at all the mapping apps on iOS. Also, I simply cancel the previous request before calling it again, if my method has been hit again before the previous one finished.

Comment: I don't think it will take in consideration if you cancel the request. And as you can see in your app, the server request take long time to complete, and also it's possible to not find the address that match the your string until the last characters